# Elasticsearch : Filter does not work with wildcard query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch2

Here is my query

```
POST indexName/test/_search
{
  "fields" : ["Col1"],
  "query":{
                        "filtered":{

                        "query":{


                        "wildcard": {

                            "Col1": {

                                  "value": "*zxc*"
                               }
                            }

                          },
                        "filter":
                {
                  "term": { 

                    "Col2": "val" 

                  }
                }
                    }

            }
}
```

so i want to do a wildcard on `Col1` for the value `*zxc*` and i want only those values where `Col2` is `val` this returns 0 hits. is there anything wrong with my syntax?

The wildcard query works independently if i remove the filter.

**Edit**

this works

```
POST indexName/test/_search
{
  "fields" : ["Col1"],
  "query":{
                        "filtered":{


                        "filter":
                {
                  "term": { 

                    "Col2": "val" 

                  }
                }
                    }

            }
}
```

sample document returned

```
{
        "_index": "indexName",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "oainfubgvwurebetrnjt",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "Col1": [
            "uyiwebvybg iuowenbgubnrwev  uirbgvuire3bv  vuirbg"
          ]
        }
      }
```

and so does this

```
POST indexName/test/_search
{
  "fields" : ["Col1"],
  "query":{
                        "wildcard": {

                            "Col1": {

                                  "value": "*zxc*"
                               }
                            }

            }
}
```

sample document returned

```
{
        "_index": "indexName",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "aofnhuiwegbnweu",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "Col1": [
            "idasihid huwbgbuiwb iuohfuweb zxc oifjhwgbu"
          ]
        }
      }
```

so both of these queries work independently. How do i combine them?

**Edit**

here is what a typical response looks like with both fields included

{
            "_index": "indexName",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "aofnhuiwegbnweu",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
              "Col1": [
                "idasihid huwbgbuiwb iuohfuweb zxc oifjhwgbu"
              ],

```
        "Col2": [
                "asd"
              ]
        }
      }
```

for query

```
POST indexName/test/_search
    {
      "fields" : ["Col1","Col2"],
      "query":{
                            "wildcard": {

                                "Col1": {

                                      "value": "*zxc*"
                                   }
                                }

                }
    }
```

similar results for the other one

Comment: How about if you remove the wildcard query. Does the document you are looking for get returned with just the filter on Col2?

Comment: yes, please see the edit. both queries work independently

Comment: Odd...I can't see anything wrong with the query. Can you provide a sample document that is being returned successfully with both your independent queries?

Comment: i added the sample documents. please see the edit.

Comment: the sample document does not show values for `Col2`

Comment: Since you have `"fields" : ["Col1"],`, we don't get to see the value in `Col2`. Just for debugging, can you include `Col2` in the response? Thanks.

Comment: i will add that, but i dont need Col2 in results. it is just another string

Comment: Document returned when you run `"Col2": "val" ` query is different from the one which is returned when you run `"value": "*zxc*"` query.

Comment: yes, more often than not it will be, but i am looking for the set where the results of the two queries intersect

Comment: please see the edit. i have added a sample result with `Col2` included. i dont know how that adds anything

Comment: Has anyone been able to run the wildcard query with filter? I just want to know that the concept works.